# TypeError: write() argument must be str, not None

Tags: python, error-handling, typeerror, openai-api

Error

When i run the code to generate article using openai, i get this json output, the bold part is the article:

ChatCompletion(id='chatcmpl-97M4Sn1HgR5gYTdc5VCwbw69FxwAz', choices=[Choice(finish_reason='stop', index=0, logprobs=None, message=ChatCompletionMessage(**content**="**Title: Understanding the Intricacies of an Immigration Visa: A Comprehensive Guide \n\nIntroduction\n\nImmigration is a significant life-changing decision, requiring thoughtful planning and execution. A crucial component of this process involves securing an immigration visa. This guide aims to provide comprehensive information about the immigration visa process, helping you navigate this journey with ease.\n\nWhat is an Immigration Visa?\n\nAn immigration visa grants authorization to individuals to live, work, or study in a foreign country**

**permanently. Unlike a non-immigrant visa, such as a tourist or student visa, an immigration visa is the stepping stone to becoming a permanent resident or citizen of the host nation. \n\nTypes of Immigration Visas\n\nImmigration visas can be broadly classified into two categories: Family-sponsored visas and Employment-based visas.\n\n1. Family-Sponsored Visas\n\nThese visas are issued to individuals who have close relatives, such as a spouse, children, or parents, residing as citizens or permanent residents in the destination country.\n\n2. Employment-Based Visas\n\nThese visas are granted to individuals who are recruited by employers in the destination country. The applicant’s skills, qualifications, and job offer play a pivotal role in obtaining this visa. \n\nApplication Process for an Immigration Visa\n\nApplying for an immigration visa involves several steps:\n\n1. Petition Filing: An eligible relative or prospective employer must file a petition on your behalf with the U.S. Citizenship and Immigration Services (USCIS). \n\n2. Petition Approval: Once the USCIS approves the petition, it is**

**sent to the National Visa Center. The applicant is then informed about the necessary fees and documents required.\n\n3. Visa Interview: After all the documents and fees are submitted, the applicant is called for an interview at the U.S. embassy or consulate in their home country.\n\n4. Visa Approval: If the visa officer finds the applicant eligible, the immigration visa is approved.\n\nUnderstanding the Visa Bulletin\n\nThe Visa Bulletin, published monthly by the U.S. Department of State, is a valuable resource for applicants. It provides information about the availability of immigration visas, categorized by country and preference.\n\nThe Challenges of Immigration Visas\n\nWhile the prospect of moving to a new country is exciting, the process of obtaining an immigration visa can be complex and daunting. It involves stringent procedures, documentation, and legal formalities. Moreover, the waiting time can be lengthy, depending on the country and visa category.\n\nConclusion\n\nSecuring an immigration visa is the first step towards realizing your dreams of starting afresh in a new country. While the process may be challenging, having a clear understanding of the visa process can make the journey smoother and more manageable. \n\nRemember, obtaining an immigration visa requires patience, perseverance, and meticulous planning. Therefore, it's recommended to seek professional advice or consultation if you're finding the process overwhelming. The dream of living in your desired country is worth**

**the wait and effort, opening doors to new opportunities and experiences. \n\nKeywords: Immigration visa, non-immigrant visa, family-sponsored visa, employment-based visa, USCIS, National Visa Center, Visa Bulletin.**", role='assistant', function_call=None, tool_calls=None))], created=1711540164, model='gpt-4-0613', object='chat.completion', system_fingerprint=None, usage=CompletionUsage(completion_tokens=616, prompt_tokens=43, total_tokens=659))

When I run the code to extract just the content:

***generated_content = response.choices[0].message.content***

i get this error:

*TypeError: write() argument must be str, not None*

I am expecting to get a file with the content saved in it

Comment: Please post your code and remove all the irrellevant info that you posted

Comment: You've not shown any code that calls `write()` - where is this error coming from?